# The command prompt(cmd.exe) closes immediately without leaving enough time for me to even feed a command

Tags: command-line

I have windows 7 on my computer as well as laptop. On both , I am facing this problem. The command prompt closes immediately within few milliseconds

EDIT : - I was able to open the command prompt and the registry edit on safe mode. Does this hint something?

Comment: How are you starting the command prompt?

Comment: Have you tried with a different user?

Comment: @DavidPostill from the start menu ... cmd.exe

Comment: Try the accepted answer in this [so] question [CMD.exe closes immediately after calling (Win7 64)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5374418)

Comment: In the registry node `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\ ` for some reason there was `AUTORUN` key with "EXIT" inside

Comment: @DavidPostill My regedit closes itself too :(

Comment: Have you tried safe mode? Sounds like you have a virus.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion is that you may be a victim of potential malware or even a virus which is actively monitoring running processes and terminating known ones which could be considered intrusive.

I would suggest downloading a 3rd party tool to scan your computer for known malware / virus signatures. Please consider reading [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 0):

> Follow the steps provided below to resolve the issue:
>
> Method 1: Boot into safe mode and check if the issue persists.
>
> Start your computer in safe mode
>
> Method 2: You may follow the steps below to keep the command prompt
>   open.
>
> a.       Open an elevated Command Prompt window. To open an elevated
>   Command Prompt, click Start, type cmd, right-click Command Prompt, and
>   then click Run as administrator.
>
> b.      Type the following command and press ENTER: cmd /k netstat
>   c.       Exit the Command Prompt window.   Method 3: If the above
>   method does not resolve the issue, you may follow the below steps.
>
> a.       Right click your Start button,
>
> b.      Select properties, customize
>
> c.       Put a check mark at 'Display Run'   Method 4: Try performing
>   SFC scan on the computer.
>
> How to use the System File Checker tool to troubleshoot missing or
>   corrupted system files on Windows Vista or on Windows 7
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833 Hope this information helps.

From [Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/my-command-prompt-opens-and-then-quickly-closes/49d49ec6-882a-4328-854b-48d036684290?auth=1)

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing) and make sure you "block quote" quoted material ([Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help)). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Comment: i did find this while searching and it didnt help